# How do I convert a JDBC:Oracle Date into a DateTime for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, oracle, jdbc, sinatra, sequel

I finally figured it out how to connect my Sinatra app via JDBC and Sequel to an existing Oracle database.

Now my problem is that I would like to show the Date fields from the Oracle DB as Date with time.

Quick date definition from Oracle:

> Valid date range from January 1, 4712
>   BC to December 31, 9999 AD. The
>   default format is determined
>   explicitly by the NLS_DATE_FORMAT
>   parameter or implicitly by the
>   NLS_TERRITORY parameter. The size is
>   fixed at 7 bytes. This datatype
>   contains the datetime fields YEAR,
>   MONTH, DAY, **HOUR, MINUTE, and SECOND**.
>   It does not have fractional seconds or
>   a time zone.

In Ruby I would like to do this:

```
row_added.strftime('%d.%B %Y %H:%M:%S') => 09.May 2011 00:00:00
```

But a Ruby Date does not have hours or minutes.

Instead I have to do this at the SQL level to see the time:

```
to_char(row_added, 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:ss') => 09.05.11 08:33:31
```

It is working as expected, but should not be the best solution for this.

Can anyone tell me how I can get Ruby Sequel to convert this to a Time or DateTime value and not Date?

Answer (score 3):

Sequel converts `Java::JavaSQL::Timestamp` and `Java::JavaSQL::Time` classes to ruby `Time/DateTim`, and `Java::JavaSQL::Date` classes to ruby `Date` (https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/lib/sequel/adapters/jdbc.rb#L579).  If Oracle uses subclass of `Java::JavaSQL::Date` but includes time information, they are doing it wrong, they should be subclassing `Java::JavaSQL::Timestamp`.

Anyway, to fix this, you'd need to add the `Dataset#convert_type` method to the `jdbc/oracle subadapter` (https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/lib/sequel/adapters/jdbc/oracle.rb) and handle whatever the Oracle specific date type is.  Please submit a patch if you get it working correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Try this method: [strptime](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strptime/class)

Comment: The returned Object from sequel is a Date. The date object does not contain any hours and minutes. Therefor I can not create the string for the strptime method. Or am I going about this the wrong way?